# Extract max values from a matrix in R (random selection)

Tags: r

Given a matrix, extracting the row names of the column with max values is a common problem.

```
sapply(mat,2,which.max)

mat<-matrix(list(20,0,0,80,80,0,
                 20,0,40,0,40,20,
                 40,0,40,20,20,0,
                 0,80,40,20,20,20),ncol=6,byrow=T)
rownames(mat)<-c("A","C","G","T")
```

But here, some columns have two similar max values (in the example matrix, col 3 and 4). By default the script chooses "A" has the row with the max column value in col 3 and 4. I am having trouble in writing a script to randomly select between two row names (A and T) wherein both have max values in column 3 and 4. 
Any help with the scripting is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rank` function comes in handy:

```
> apply(mat,2,function(x) which(rank(-unlist(x), ties.method="random") == 1))
[1] 3 4 4 1 1 2
> apply(mat,2,function(x) which(rank(-unlist(x), ties.method="random") == 1))
[1] 3 4 3 1 1 2
> apply(mat,2,function(x) which(rank(-unlist(x), ties.method="random") == 1))
[1] 3 4 4 1 1 4
```

The `ties.method="random"` part is crucial for resolving the ties in a random fashion.

Comment: +1 I haven't had cause to use the rank function before. Could come in handy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading the [documentation for `which.max`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.min.html), which suggests using `which.is.max` from **nnet**. Either borrow that algorithm or use that package.

```
> library(nnet)
> which.is.max
function (x) 
{
    y <- seq_along(x)[x == max(x)]
    if (length(y) > 1L) 
        sample(y, 1L)
    else y
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000013fda7c8>
<environment: namespace:nnet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `sample` from those `rownames` which have values equal to the `max` value in that column:

```
mat<-matrix(c(20,0,0,80,80,0,
                 20,0,40,0,40,20,
                 40,0,40,20,20,0,
                 0,80,40,20,20,20),ncol=6,byrow=T)
rownames(mat)<-c("A","C","G","T")

set.seed(123)
apply( mat, 2 , function(x) sample( c( rownames(mat)[ which( x == max(x) ) ] ) , 1 ) )
#[1] "G" "T" "G" "A" "A" "C"

set.seed(1234)
apply( mat, 2 , function(x) sample( c( rownames(mat)[ which( x == max(x) ) ] ) , 1 ) )
#[1] "G" "T" "G" "A" "A" "T"
```

p.s. I'm not sure why you construct the matrix data usin a `list` object - matrices are vectors.